# C++/CLI optional arguments

Tags: c++-cli, optional-parameters

Why i cannot declare default arguments for member functions of a managed type or generic functions? `C# 4.0` introduced [Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx); there is a similar thing for `CLI`?

I do not understand why is not possible to declare a method like this:

```
void Optional(int argument = 0);
```

And then when I call `Optional();` the compiler does not *translate* this call into: `Optional(0);`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the C++/CLI Compiler doesn't emit the correct IL directive for that. It doesn't emit the directive `.param [1] = int32(0)`, which C# uses for recognizing default parameters. If you open the generated assembly in ILDasm, you'll see it.

A way that *compiles* would be to use the attributes `Optional` and `DefaultParameterValue` from the `System::Runtime::InteropServices` namespace, but C# doesn't use those for default parameters, so currently there's no easy way around creating an overload.

You can find the question asking about those Attributes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974528/93652

Comment: So the C++/CLI compiler doesn't know how to generate the directive. I hope that with VS (12 ?) the problem will be solved.

Comment: I hope so, too. Interestingly it seems that languages handle this differently. I heard VB.Net does it by using the Attributes. So i guess it would be best if both attributes and the directive were generated.