# C++/CLI: How do I use the CallerMemberNameAttribute in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, optional-parameters, callermembername

In C# and VB.Net I can use the *CallerMemberNameAttribute* to get the name of the invoker as a string:

```
public void Caller([CallerMemberName]string memberName = "")
{
   Debug.Print(memberName);
}
```

I would like to do the same in C++/CLI but somehow I cannot get it working. Tried several constructions and I am starting to wonder whether the C++/CLI compiler supports this attribute.

Here is a (simplified) implementation:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
public ref class InvokeExample
{
    Invoke([CallerMemberName][Optional]String^ name)
    {
        Debug::Print(name);
    }
}
```

When invoking this method in a C# application the value of name is null. Also tried with the attribute *DefaultParameterValue* but it didn't help either. Now running out of ideas.

Obvious answer would be, why not implementing in C#? 
Well, in this specific case I am limited to C++/CLI.

Comment: No point in trying, this is not implemented in the C++ compiler.  C++/CLI was frozen in 2005.  You'll have to use the [StackTrace class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2652591/17034).

Comment: Be aware that Hans' suggestion implies a severe performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

I used reflector to view the differences between the C++/CLI and the C#/VB.Net version and they looked exactly the same.

Then used ILDASM and now I think I know why it doesn't work (after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974237)).

Here's the il code:

C++/CLI

```
.method public hidebysig instance string 
        Caller([opt] string methodName) cil managed
{
  .param [1]
  .custom instance void [System]System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribute::.ctor(object) = ( 01 00 0E 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  ldarg.1
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method ClassCPP::Caller
```

C#

```
.method public hidebysig instance string 
        Caller([opt] string methodName) cil managed
{
  .param [1] = ""
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.1
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method ClassCS::Caller
```

IL code from VB.Net differs from C# as follows:

```
.param [1] = nullref
```

I suspect that because the C++/CLI emits DefaultParameterValue instead of initializing .param[1] with a default value the C# compiler won't convert the value to the caller member name.

Would be handy if the MSDN pages describe such limitations for C++/CLI projects. Would save us a lot of time.